# Error in a string reversal program in emu8086

Tags: string, assembly, offset, x86-16, emu8086

I tried a string reversal program, but emu8086 is showing me an error message

> (12)offset calculation error

What is wrong with the line `LEA DI,STR2+LEN-1` ?

```
DATA SEGMENT
STR1 DB 'HELLO'
LEN EQU $-STR1
STR2 DB 20 DUP(0)
DATA ENDS
CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA, ES:DATA
START: MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX
MOV ES,AX
LEA SI,STR1
LEA DI,STR2+LEN-1
MOV CX,LEN
UP: CLD
LODSB
STD
STOSB
LOOP UP
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
CODE ENDS
END START
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using emu8086, but the following will correct your line 12:

```
mov di, offset STR2 + LEN - 1
```

The shorter way to obtain an address is writing `mov si, offset STR1` (uses **3** bytes) instead of `lea si, STR1` (uses **4** bytes).

---

The loop ends with the direction flag still set!
It will always be a good idea to have the direction flag cleared before invoking any system function:

```
...
LOOP UP
CLD            ; Add this to clear direction flag
MOV AH,4CH     ; DOS.Terminate
INT 21H
...
```